# how to make the homepage responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm a Newbie with `CSS`, I want to make a responsive design for mobile IE. Now "it appear as a blank page",But it's working well in Google chrome and other rest of browsers :-)

Below is my codes that's I used

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="marquee">
            <marquee scrollamount="3" direction="right" dir="ltr">
                 <h3 align="center" style="color:#804000;font-size:large;margin-top:0px;"><strong>  
    <img height="37" src="http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/image21.png">
        </strong></h3>

            </marquee>
        </div>
<a class="button" id="btn1" href="http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/site.html"></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url("http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/bg.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.marquee {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    width: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
    background-image: url("http://www.ghadaalsamman.com/new/images/enter.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 53px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.button {
    padding: 5px;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width:500px) {
    #btn1{
        background-size: 100% auto;
    }
}
```

*[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0sagal/x4STT/)*

*[Desktop View](http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/)*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont use marquee element

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Work great for me on Windows Phone 8.1

I don't think there is an issue with responsiveness, I checked on desktop resizing my browser on IE and also on Windows Phone.

Comment: i still have some problems with landscape

Comment: what are ur problems, can u attach a screenshot?

Comment: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/&device=iphone-5&orientation=landscape

Comment: iPad portrait · width: 768px

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http://ghadaalsamman.com/new/&device=ipad&orientation=portrait